# TFS 2010 Build SharePoint with WCF Service

Tags: wcf, sharepoint, build, tfs

I am attempting to set up some continuous integration for a clients SharePoint environment.

The issue I am running into is with SharePoint projects that include a WCF service.
The project in question builds fine but fails when it attempts to package and deploy on the build server.

The project builds and deploys fine from Visual Studio, the problem only occurs on the TFS Build server.

The Error thrown by the Build Agent is as follows:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\SharePointTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.targets (378): The "ValidatePackage" task failed unexpectedly. System.InvalidOperationException: The project service is not a serialized SharePoint project service.    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Tasks.ValidatePackage.OnCheckParameters()    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Tasks.BuildTask.Execute()    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, Boolean& taskResult)



The following is the error from MSBuild Logs :

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\SharePointTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.targets(378,5): error MSB4018: The "ValidatePackage" task failed unexpectedly. [C:\BuildsNew\4\SharePrice\SharePrice_Dev\Sources\SharePrice\SharePrice.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\SharePointTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.targets(378,5): error MSB4018: System.InvalidOperationException: The project service is not a serialized SharePoint project service. [C:\BuildsNew\4\SharePrice\SharePrice_Dev\Sources\SharePrice\SharePrice.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\SharePointTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.targets(378,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Tasks.ValidatePackage.OnCheckParameters() [C:\BuildsNew\4\SharePrice\SharePrice_Dev\Sources\SharePrice\SharePrice.csproj]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We usualy see this error if you only reference the DLL's using the registry described in (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff622991.aspx) and/or didn't install everything correctly. In our case installing SharePoint 2010 completely (without configuring it) on the buildserver removes this error.